# How would I create a CBV using django rest framework which will either retrieve a model instance or create a new one?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a person model with the fields first_name, last_name and email.  I'd like to send these fields to a view that would check the DB for an existing instance. If there is one the ID will be returned, if not a new instance will be created and the new ID returned. Using a standard FBV I would do this (cut down version, minus validation etc):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mysite.models import Person
import json

def get_or_create_person(request):
    try:
        person = Person.objects.get(first_name=request.POST['first_name'],
            last_name=request.POST['last_name'], email=request.POST['email'])
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        person = Person(first_name=request.POST['first_name'],
            last_name=request.POST['last_name'], email=request.POST['email'])
        person.save()

    response = {'id': person.id}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response))
```

Is there any real point in converting it to use a CBV and tie it in with the rest framework and if so how would I go about doing it? The main reason I want it as a CBV is so I can use mixins etc that I already include in other parts of my app.

Edit: I thought about using the ViewSets available through the rest framework but they split this functionality into GET and POST methods, with get retrieving a record and post either updating or creating one. I basically need a view which can accept either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to kinda combine the get and post functions as follows:

```
class GetOrCreateCustomerView(APIView):
    '''
    API endpoint that takes an email address, first name & surname and then
    either returns the matching customer id or creates a new customer and
    returns that id
    '''

    required_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        request_data = request.GET
        response = self.get_customer_id(request_data)

        return JSONResponse(response)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        request_data = request.POST
        response = self.get_customer_id(request_data)

        return JSONResponse(response)

    def get_customer_id(self, data):
        kwargs = {}
        for f in self.required_fields:
            if f in data:
                kwargs[f] = data[f]
            else:
                return None

        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(**kwargs)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            customer = Customer(**kwargs)
            customer.save()

        if customer.id is not None:
            response = {'customer_id': customer.id}
        else:
            response = {
                'error': 'Please provide a first name, surname and email address'
            }

        return response
```

The JSONResponse referenced here is the one from the [rest framework docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization.html#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer).

Answer (score 0):

for classbased views in django-rest-framework this is usually done by:

1. a GET request to the resource will retrieve records
2. a POST request to the same resource will create a record

I believe there are a couple examples of this in the django rest framework documentation

Comment: I'd seen this when I was reading the docs, but it doesn't really help me. This separates retrieving and creating a record into 2 distinct methods of the view, basing its decision on which one to use on whether the request is a GET or a POST. What I need is a view which will accept either a GET or a POST and then return the ID of an existing record or create a new one.